# Why does Car Play disconnect when I go in/out of WiFi range?

Tags: iphone, car-integration

On my 2018 Honda CR-V, when using Car Play from my iPhone 7, it frequently disconnects when entering or leaving WiFi signal range. The head unit then says "No Device Connected". Usually, I have to unplug and re-plug my iPhone to bring Car Play back up.

This problem can occur at some non-obvious places around town, because my phone can connect to my ISP's WiFi access points which are all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this. I removed the CloudFlare 1.1.1.1 app from my phone.

That app provides fast, secure DNS connections. It looks like a VPN profile to your phone, although it is not actually a VPN. Apparently 1.1.1.1 (and maybe some other VPN apps) are breaking CarPlay. I don't know why there is an interaction between networking and CarPlay, but in my before and after tests, it was rock solid once I got rid of the CloudFlare app.

The DNS app seemed like a good idea, but it was not worth all the trouble it caused.

Comment: Almost all vpn profiles cause problems with CarPlay, from my reading and experience. While Cloudflare is not a VPN it does use a VPN profile to direct your dns traffic to their servers. I've found that no matter which vpn product I try, it's the same experience on my CarPlay.